# Webpack gives undefined for adding Javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, module, webpack

I'm new to webpack , I trying to add skrollr.js to webpack configurations to use it whenever required, but I not sure what is the right approach for this , what I find that either using alias or export as module , but something is missing

webpack.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
  entry: ["./app/scripts/main.js","./app/scripts/skrollr.js"],
  output: {
     filename: "./app/scripts/bundle.js"
     },
  resolve: {
     extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
     alias: {"skrollr" : "./skrollr.js"}
     },
   module: {
      loaders :[
      {test:/\.(jsx|js)$/,exclude: /node_modules/,loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window' },
      {test:/skrollr.js/,exclude: /node_modules/,loader: 'exports?skrollr'}
           ]
      }
};
```

I have a file that is main.js which requires skroller variable , in the old way it was in a script tag in HTML loaded before the main so it is available ,

main.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
   require('./skrollr.js');
   var s = skrollr.init({
```

but when ever i run the webpack using

```
 node_modules/.bin/webpack -display-error-detalis
```

it gives an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: skrollr is not defined
```

clicking of the error file :

```
/*** IMPORTS FROM imports-loader ***/
 var jQuery = require("jquery");
 var $ = require("jquery");

 /*** EXPORTS FROM exports-loader ***/
 module.exports = skrollr;
 }.call(window));
 /*****************
  ** WEBPACK FOOTER
  ** ./app/scripts/skrollr.js
  ** module id = 2
  ** module chunks = 0
  **/
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need an alias for it, I would only use alias to remove the need relative paths in deeply nested import statements.

Does skrollr.js export anything? Have you tried

```
var skrollr = require('./skrollr.js');
```

...without the alias config in webpack.

Also, if you were to use aliases the pathname has to be absolute so webpack can find it

Comment: skrollr does not export anything it is just a js library 
I removed the alias and add the
  `var skrollr = require('./skrollr.js');`
still not defined

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass your required module to variable

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
   require('./skrollr.js'); //you are just requiring it
   var s = skrollr.init({
```

Change to

```
 var skorllr = require('./skrollr.js');
 (function () {
     'use strict';          
 var s = skrollr.init({
```

and this line to be removed

```
{test:/skrollr.js/,exclude: /node_modules/,loader: 'exports?skrollr'}
```

you are getting error because if it. when you are bundling your files it is exporting skrollr which does not exist the time you run your code

> NOTE:- you are already testing all js files with 
>   {test:/.(jsx|js)$/,exclude: /node_modules/,loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window' }

**you don't need to test separate skrollr.js**

Comment: still giving undefined

Comment: move var skorllr = require('./skrollr.js'); outside of iife (immediately-invoked-function-expression) and it will work.

Comment: I installed this library for test with npm and required skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js and it worked for me. Have you manually downloaded the library? Weird that it is not working for you. I can look into your code if it is on github ?

Comment: no, i did not install it through npm I downloaded it , what I'm doing now I'm trying to add webpack on one of my old projects , so in the old way I download it and add it in a `script` tag

Comment: Ok thats hard way. You gave skrollr as entey point also you don't neee that either alias. If you could share your code so i would be try to find out what is causing this issue.

Comment: remove this from webpack
 {test:/skrollr.js/,exclude: /node_modules/,loader: 'exports?skrollr'}
and it works. you are already testing all js files so no need for this.

Comment: thanks it works , but is this a wrong way of dealing with the js libraries , and the loader test that I used , is it import all the js files not and put it in the global scope or , importing the skoller is not related to any of this loader condition

Comment: Läder is used to test a file and compile that file of needs. Say if you are working with ES6 then you have to use loader to compile into es5 which browser understand much better. Imorting skrollr is not related to this condition if it is built in es5.